# Adding border to TextView programmatically

Tags: java, android, textview, border, transparent

What I am trying to do is add a border around the TextView, while the middle of the text view should be transparent. Here is my code:

```
LayerDrawable borders = getBorders(
   Color.TRANSPARENT, // Background color
   Color.parseColor("#CCCCCC"), // Border color
   2, // Left border in pixels
   2, // Top border in pixels
   2, // Right border in pixels
   2 // Bottom border in pixels
);

TextView cell = (TextView) super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
cell.setBackground(borders);

// Custom method to generate one or multi side border for a view
protected LayerDrawable getBorders(int bgColor, int borderColor,
                                   int left, int top, int right, int bottom){
// Initialize new color drawables
ColorDrawable borderColorDrawable = new ColorDrawable(borderColor);
ColorDrawable backgroundColorDrawable = new ColorDrawable(bgColor);

// Initialize a new array of drawable objects
Drawable[] drawables = new Drawable[]{
    borderColorDrawable,
    backgroundColorDrawable
};

// Initialize a new layer drawable instance from drawables array
LayerDrawable layerDrawable = new LayerDrawable(drawables);

// Set padding for background color layer
layerDrawable.setLayerInset(
    1, // Index of the drawable to adjust [background color layer]
    left, // Number of pixels to add to the left bound [left border]
    top, // Number of pixels to add to the top bound [top border]
    right, // Number of pixels to add to the right bound [right border]
    bottom // Number of pixels to add to the bottom bound [bottom border]
);

// Finally, return the one or more sided bordered background drawable
return layerDrawable;
```

However, the code above produced the text view with light grey color. The middle of the text view is not transparent at all. How do I fix this?

Comment: this is because you are using two `ColorDrawable`s one on top of the another - use `GradientDrawable` instead of `LayerDrawable`

Comment: @pskink I see I see! Thanks so much for pointing it out!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create drawable file

**abc.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#00ffffff" />
            <corners android:radius="2dp" />
            <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#e1e1e1" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

and set background

```
cell.setBackground(R.drawable.abc);
```

and you can change background color to change `<solid android:color="#00ffffff" />` color in xml file

Comment: Is there any way to set the opacity of the border color using the drawable.xml above?

Comment: @ guest176969 yes

Comment: How to achieve it?

Comment: choose color from color picker and set opacity (like increase or decrease) from picker

Answer (score 3):

You can try this. It will help you to add border on textview programatically

```
GradientDrawable gradientDrawableDefault = new GradientDrawable();
gradientDrawableDefault.setStroke((int) context.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.dp1), ContextCompat.getColor(context,R.color.color_player_line));
gradientDrawableDefault.setCornerRadius(
context.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.dp5));
gradientDrawableDefault.setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

set gradientDrawableDefault in background of textview.

Comment: I see I see! Thanks so much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this below code for button or textview or Edittext...........Enjoy

```
 button.setBackground(getAngleDrawable(backgroundcolor, new float[]{20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20},strokeWidth,strokeColor));



 public static GradientDrawable getAngleDrawable(int solidColor,float[] _radius,int strokeWidth,int strokeColor)
    {
        GradientDrawable gradientDrawable= new GradientDrawable();
        gradientDrawable.setColor(solidColor);
        gradientDrawable.setShape(GradientDrawable.RECTANGLE);
        gradientDrawable.setCornerRadii(_radius);
        gradientDrawable.setStroke(strokeWidth, strokeColor);
        return gradientDrawable;
    }
```

You can use shape of your own:

```
 gradientDrawable.setShape(GradientDrawable.RECTANGLE);
```